# HighlightJS invalid regular expression

Tags: regex, cdn, highlight.js

We use [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) for syntax highlighting in our web application. This has been working well for months with our customers in the US, India, Australia, etc. and still is today.

We just onboarded our first customer in Tel Aviv, Israel, and they have been experiencing an odd issue across multiple browsers and operating systems (including latest Chrome 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Mac OSX)

`curl https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js` returns the file with the invalid regexp below:

```
/([Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(<[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(\s*,\s*[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*)*>)?\s+)+[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s*\(/
```

[image]

Can anyone guess as to why this is happening? Is the CDN just returning a different file to requests made in Israel?

Comment: You may easily [see at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/C8YqiQ/1) the `€-Ê` are out of order.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes but try `curl https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js` I'm guessing you'll find that this regexp is correct. Why does the file have a correct regexp in the US but not in Isreal?

Comment: That is an encoding issue. The `Ã€-Ê¸` should be replaced with `\u00C0-\u02B8` (or, in a string literal, `\\u00C0-\\u02B8`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see, thanks. How would you suggest we fix this? Self-host a version of `highlight.min.js` on our own CDN?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that. Perhaps, a bug report should be made. Probably, there is a way to emulate a different locale environment.

Comment: Can you provide origin URL for that one as well? Did you tried purging?

Comment: @DusanGligoric what do you mean by "origin URL"?

Comment: You provided CDN URL, origin URL as in an URL where we could download the asset from your server directly. @Apollo

Answer (score 1):

Stated error is caused due to encoding issue. Specifying encoding as `"utf-8"` solved the issue for me.

Include below in your html `<head>` tag.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: As of Highlight.js 10.3.1 (released today) the CDN distributable (at least the Javascript code portions) should all be encoded properly as ASCII so this should no longer be a requirement. (to specify `charset`)